# VS2010 ASPX Design View, vertical scrollbar disabled

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010

In VS2010 working on an ASP.NET project, when opening an ASPX page in the IDE and viewingin Design mode, the vertical scrollbar is disabled.  The horizontal scrollbar remains enabled. It doesn't seem to matter what page I open.  Note that I am using a single Master page.

I have tried searching other posts, including running “devenv /resetsettings” 
[http://forums.asp.net/t/1149955.aspx?Scroll+Bar+doesn+t+show+up+in+Design+View+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1149955.aspx?Scroll%20Bar%20doesn%20t%20show%20up%20in%20Design%20View%20)

however this didn't solve it.  This thread also makes mention of the actual content itself (ie "overflow-x: hidden;") being a potential cause, however that would be pathetic if source code affected how the IDE's vertical scrollbar behaves.

Any help would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

David

[image]

Comment: Have you found the solution? My design view is completely disabled with a  circle slash (/), totally not able to use.